# Changing file names in sub-folders following a number extracted from the sub-folders

Tags: command-line, bash, files, gnome-shell, batch-rename

I have a folder with several sub-folders, inside which I have a file with same name  in all sub-folders. For example:

- `abc/def_0/ghi.jpg`
- `abc/def_5/ghi.jpg`
- `abc/def_10/ghi.jpg`
- ***...***
- `abc/pqr_0/ghi.jpg`
- `abc/pqr_5/ghi.jpg`
- `abc/pqr_10/ghi.jpg`

I would like to rename this particular file (`ghi.jpg`) in all sub-folders as:

- `abc/def_0/def_xyz_0.jpg`
- `abc/def_5/def_xyz_5.jpg`
- `abc/def_10/def_xyz_10.jpg`
- ***...***
- `abc/pqr_0/pqr_xyz_0.jpg`
- `abc/pqr_5/pqr_xyz_5.jpg`
- `abc/pqr_10/pqr_xyz_10.jpg`

I would appreciate any help, as I was not able to find a solution for this. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu. Please fix the formatting to make your question more readable, and explain in words the rules for renaming, so we don't need to guess from your examples.

Comment: @hello_world_007 I've edited this, but I recommend you review my edit. If you don't like it, you can roll it back, edit again yourself, or both. In particular, some occurrences of `0` in filenames appeared where you seemed to mean `10`. Otherwise, for example, you would have listed `abc/def_0/ghi.jpg` twice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Perl rename command [`file-rename`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/file-rename.1p.html) for this. If you're unfamiliar with this tool, I recommend you run `file-rename --version` to see if you have it--any output other than an error means you do. A few Ubuntu releases don't come with it by default, so you might not have it, in which case you can get it by installing the `rename` package. (The "command not found" error if you don't have it will likely even tell you about that.)

`cd` to the `abc` directory whose subdirectories contain the files you want to rename and run this. Then if the renaming operations it shows are really the ones you want, run it again without `-n` to do the actual renaming.

```
file-rename -n 's|^(.+)_(\d+)/ghi\.jpg$|$1_$2/$1_xyz_$2.jpg|' */ghi.jpg
```

This generates the list of files to rename using a shell glob and passes it as arguments to `file-rename` to be renamed. It assumes that you want:

- To rename files called exactly `ghi.jpg` that reside directly in subdirectories--named ending in `_` followed by digits--of the directory `abc`.
- Each file's new name to be its containing directory *without* the trailing underscore and digits, followed by `xyz`, followed the trailing underscore and digits from its containing directory's name.

---

The way that works is that `s|pattern|substitution|` operates on files whose paths, as they were passed as arguments to `file-rename`, match *`pattern`* (interpreted as a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) in [the Perl dialect](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html)). The operation it performs is to rename them using the specified *`substitution`*. Files whose names didn't contain a match to *`pattern`* wouldn't be renamed. There's nothing special about `|` as the choice of separator; I just don't want to use the usual `/` since that's appearing in the paths.

In the pattern `^(.+)_(\d+)/ghi\.jpg$`:

- `^` matches the beginning of the path and `$` matches the end. This allows only matches on the entirety of each path passed in, rather than just any part of it.

  (To address one possible point of confusion: the paths being passed in are still [relative paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Absolute_and_relative_paths) like `def_0/ghi.jpg`, not absolute paths like `/home/you/abc/def_0/ghi.jpg`. When people talk about "full paths," they typically mean absolute paths. By "the entirety of the path" I just mean each whole argument passed in rather than a smaller substring of it.)
- `(.+)` matches and *captures* ([`(` `)`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)) a sequence of one or more ([`+`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)) of any character ([`.`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)). This goes into the first capture group.
- `_` matches itself, a literal underscore character.
- `(\d+)` matches and *captures* ([`(` `)`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)) a sequence of one or more ([`+`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)) digits ([`\d`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html)). This goes into the second capture group.
- `/` matches itself, a literal slash character. (It doesn't behave as a delimiter because we used `|` as a delimiter instead.)
- `ghi` matches the literal text `ghi`.
- `\.` matches just a `.` character. The `\` [escapes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) the `.`; otherwise, the `.` [would mean](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) "any character."
- `jpg` matches the literal text `jpg`.

The substitution `$1_$2/$1_xyz_$2.jpg` signifies:

- Text that was placed in the first capture group (`$1`). This is the text that matched `.+` in the pattern.
- An underscore, `_`.
- Text that was placed in the second capture group (`$2`). This is the text that matched `\d+` in the pattern.
- A slash, `/`.
- The first capture group (`$1`) again.
- The text `_xyz_`.
- The second capture group (`$2`) again.
- The dot, `.`. Unlike in patterns, in substitutions a `.` is not treated specially, so it need not (and should not) be escaped with an `\`.
- The text `jpg`.

---

For general documentation the use of `file-rename`, see the output of `file-rename --help`, [`man file-rename`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/file-rename.1p.html), and [this blog post](https://thepcspy.com/read/bulk-rename-files-in-ubuntu/). (I use the `file-rename` instead of the `rename` command, because on some systems `rename` is another utility. On most they are the same.)